# Не корректно работает 404 ошибка на страницах WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Когда вводишь не существующий адрес на странице в виде `site.ru/nazvanie-stranice/asdasd`

В ответ получаем 404 страницу - все правильно

Но когда переходим по адресу `site.ru/nazvanie-stranice/123`

В ответе получаем содержимое страницы `/nazvanie-stranice/` но с адресом `/nazvanie-stranice/123/`

Comment: Вопрос в том, как убрать данное упущение, не использую плагинов

Answer (score 0):

Нашел частичное решение, может кому-то подойдет или кто с прямыми руками допишет:

```
function fix_missing_404_on_paginated_page() {
  global $wp_query,$page,$paged;

  if (!isset($page)) $page = get_query_var('page');
  if (!isset($paged)) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
  if (is_page() || is_single()) {
    $realpagescount = count( explode( '<!--nextpage-->', $wp_query->post->post_content ) );

    if ( (isset($page) && isset($realpagescount) && $page >= $realpagescount) || (is_paged() && isset($paged) && $paged >=0 ) ){
      //wp_redirect( home_url() );
      nocache_headers();
      status_header( '404' );
      $wp_query->is_404=true;
      $wp_query->is_single=false;
      $wp_query->is_singular=false;
      $wp_query->post_count=0;
      $wp_query->page=0;
      $wp_query->query['page']='';
      $wp_query->query['posts']=array();
      $wp_query->query['post']=array();
      $wp_query->posts=array();
      $wp_query->post=array();
      $wp_query->queried_object=array();
      $wp_query->queried_object_id=0;
      locate_template('404.php', true);
      exit;
    }
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'fix_missing_404_on_paginated_page');
```

А проблема в том, что скрипт не отрабатывает, если в конце поставить 1, к примеру: site.ru/nazvanie-stranice/1 идет редирект на страницу поста, а если поставить 0 в конце, то загрузит по этому адресу пост.